# Is there a way to configure Facebook Business login to restrict user selection to only one Instagram account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I am using the Facebook Business Login to let the user link their Instagram account. But some Facebook profiles have multiple pages linked to many accounts.

[Example login picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfcjP.png)

Is there a way to configure the Business Login to allow user to select only one Instagram account?